# using localStorage to track a checkbox

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Got this app:

https://jsfiddle.net/Lqoe4awh/

So I have a localStorage for projects and toDos, projects are set to be saved with local storage, so are todos but I have a checkbox in the todos list modal that I don't know how to save it in localStorage and retrieve it every time you open again a modal for the same project.

tldr: when I open the project I want the checkbox to stay checked even after I close it;

```
function checkBox() {
    let allCheckBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.checkbox');
    allCheckBoxes.forEach(function(el){
        el.addEventListener('click', function(e){
                e.target.dataset.check = "checked"
                e.target.parentElement.style.textDecoration = "line-through"
                localStorage.setItem("todo" , JSON.stringify(toDoStorage))

        })
    })
}
```

Comment: I'd say, get the task from local storage, unstringify, update property 'check' of the desired task object, stringify, put it back in local storage. Since you seem to have implemented most of this already, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: It's generally better to post relevant code here instead of a link since links may go dead and not everybody can follow them. Also it's nicer to have more concise frameworks to work in ;) See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't know where to begin to get this working in your project, but here you have a simple example of how you can manage the states of checkboxes via `localStorage`.
Note that the actual uses of `localStorage` are commented out because I got a SecurityError. But I tested it in a fiddle ;)

```js
// get reference to the list
const list = document.getElementById('my-todos');
// simple helper to create a todo-item
const todoItem = ({ title, done }) => `<li>
    <span>${title}</span>
    <input type="checkbox" ${done ? 'checked' : ''}>
  </li>`;
// our tasks. reading from localStorage is commented out because "The operation is insecure"
// const tasks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos')) || 
const tasks = [
  {
    title: 'task 1',
    done: false
  },{
    title: 'task 2',
    done: true
  },{
    title: 'task 3',
    done: false
  }  
];

tasks.forEach(t => list.innerHTML += todoItem(t));

// adjust the status of a task when the corresponding checkbox is changed
list.onchange = (({ target }) => {
  tasks
  .find(({title}) => title === target.previousElementSibling.textContent)
  .done = target.checked;
  
  // again, insecure
  // localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(tasks));
});
```

```html
<ul id="my-todos"></ul>
```